# Split sub-panel box with dual feeds?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, subpanel

Is this a thing? Kinda goes with my first question on here. Again i am not an electrician nor will i be doing the work. I am the builder and owner. In the designing stages of a tiny house on wheels and im trying to figure out if we will be able to have two feeds coming in. one 20amp and one 30. on separate circuits but in the same box?

So are split sub panels with dual feeds a thing? thats my question

Running solely off a 30 amp service would be really really tight given what we need to run. Mostly propane for the larger pulls but no need for a 50amp 240 nor do we have that set up like we already do with an existing 30amp rv hookup on site. So it got me thinking the 30 amp taking some of the load off of that and putting it on a separate 20 amp feed and having both the 20 and 30 in the house at the same time yet separately...? if this makes any sense.

Comment: Please take a moment to edit your question. "Mostly propane for the large pulls." Does this mean the high energy usage appliances are propane? If so, it's irrelevant to your question.

Comment: Please don't post a duplicate of your question -- edit your original question instead to add more info, instead

Comment: yes. heat. dryer. range and hot water are all running propane.

Comment: I felt this one was a bit clearer as to what im trying to achieve

Comment: Consider itemizing the loads you intend to power. For example: A clothes washing machine with a nameplate rating of 120 V, 480 VA or 4 A or 400 W.

Answer (score 0):

If you run two feeds into one panel, the current will flow through the lower resistance path. You will end up tripping the 20 A overcurrent limiter.

If you want to supply 50 A to your tiny house using a 30 A feed (the RV connector) and a 20 A (you don't specify 120 or 240 V) feed, divide your loads into two, and install two separate subpanels.

You may find you can run the entire home off a 30 A feed. 7200 VA is a substantial amount of power.

Comment: So two separate panels each with their own load would be acceptable in this case? everything is 120v i already have a dedicated 30amp rv connection on site